# Knockout JS: Visible applies to all elements inside foreach: loop, instead of the current one

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Basically I want `visible:` to fire up only on the div i hover over, but it applies to all of them,
no matter which one I hover over.

I guess that makes sense, since I am binding to `visible:` inside `foreach:` loop, so it is applied to all of them. Is there a KnockoutJS work-around, or should I just use `$jQuery.hover()` to make it work instead?

**Html:**

```
<div>
 <div data-bind="foreach: hostGroups">
  <div data-bind="css: { style: true }, event: { mouseover: $root.showDeleteLink, mouseout: $root.hideDeleteLink }">
   <span data-bind="text: hostName"></span>
   <span class="delete-link" data-bind="visible: $root.deleteLinkVisible">this is a delete link</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = [ 
    { "hostName": "server1" }, 
    { "hostName": "server2" }, 
    { "hostName": "server3" }
]; 

var viewModel = {

    hostGroups: ko.observableArray(data),

    deleteLinkVisible: ko.observable(false),

    showDeleteLink: function() {
         viewModel.deleteLinkVisible(true);
    },

    hideDeleteLink: function() {
        viewModel.deleteLinkVisible(false);
    }

};  

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pruchai/KXtTU/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement hiding and showing the link on each individual item instead of on the root view model. For example:

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = [
    {
    "hostName": "server1"},
{
    "hostName": "server2"},
{
    "hostName": "server3"}
];

function Item(hostName) {
    var self = this;
    this.hostName = ko.observable(hostName);
    this.deleteLinkVisible = ko.observable(false);
    this.showDeleteLink = function() {
        self.deleteLinkVisible(true);
    };
    this.hideDeleteLink = function() {
        self.deleteLinkVisible(false);
    };
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.hostGroups = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
        var newItem = new Item(item.hostName);
        return newItem;
    }));

}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

**Html:**

```
<div>
 <div data-bind="foreach: hostGroups">
  <div data-bind="css: { style: true }, event: { mouseover: showDeleteLink, mouseout: hideDeleteLink }">
   <span data-bind="text: hostName"></span>
   <span class="delete-link" data-bind="visible: deleteLinkVisible">this is a delete link</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KXtTU/4/

Comment: man, i spent all day today trying to make it work with my code and failed in more ways than one. I completely understand what your code is doing, but so far i have been unable to make it work with mine :(

Comment: Aaaaand after saying that, I finally figured it out :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

showDeleteLink and hideDeleteLink in the jsfiddle you posted are throwing JavaScript errors.

Here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/KXtTU/1/

Updated JS:

```
var data = [ 
        { "hostName": "server1" }, 
        { "hostName": "server2" }, 
        { "hostName": "server3" }
    ]; 

var viewModel = {

    hostGroups: ko.observableArray(data),

    deleteLinkVisible: ko.observable(false),

    showDeleteLink: function() {
         viewModel.deleteLinkVisible(true); // added "viewModel."
    },

    hideDeleteLink: function() {
        viewModel.deleteLinkVisible(false); // added "viewModel."
    }

};  

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: thank you. i now see what I did wrong... now only if i could figure out how to stop visible: to applying to all at once :)

Comment: This might be better accomplished with css with `:hover`, do you want all the edit links to show or only for the current hovered row?

Comment: Only the current row. I know css method, but I need to apply a border to the parent div at the same time, so its ether jquery or knockout. I don't believe css is smart enough to apply to parent elements on hover :)